# How can I find out what the default (and only available) border width is on Xamarin Forms Frame?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know what the value of the border width is and where it's set in the code.

Can anyone point me to this value / area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not being used by [Frame](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/09353676ef2591829ae2610812018bf97511f6ef/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Frame.cs#L59)

```
// not currently used by frame
double IBorderElement.BorderWidth => -1d;
```

the Android [renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/52c8fe0dbd53485a244b2df5ea4a210059bc1d9c/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/FrameRenderer.cs#L193) uses a StrokeWidth of 1

```
paint.StrokeWidth = 1;
```

so does [iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/52c8fe0dbd53485a244b2df5ea4a210059bc1d9c/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/FrameRenderer.cs#L28)

```
Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
```

Comment: But a frame has a border color which I can set.  So still wondering what the default will be.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame.bordercolor?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Frame_BorderColor

Comment: see my expanded answer